# Overloading ->* to point to member object functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I have a class from another library that I'm wrapping and cannot modify, say:

```
class A {
public:
  float mem(int a);
  /* many more functions */
};
```

I'm wrapping this with a class that will hold an instance of A as a member variable:

```
class B {
public:
  A get() { return m_a; }
private:
  A m_a;
};
```

Now, to call member functions of `A`, I could definitely do:

```
B.get().mem(2);
```

This can be cumbersome with repeated calls to member functions, and writing wrappers for all of the member functions isn't really viable. So my thought was to overload the `->*` operator to call these functions:

```
B->*mem(2);
```

What I'm struggling with is the type of the function that needs to be passed to the `->*` operator. I'm actually having trouble finding any examples of anyone actually overloading this operator without completely changing its functionality. My best guess is that it would resemble something like this:

```
template<class A::func, class return_type, class... args>
return_type operator->*(A::func(args)) {
  return m_a.*(A::func(args...));
}
```

I would figure it has to  be templated, but can template deduction correctly pick out the function, its arguments, and its return type? 
Or maybe a `decltype(auto)` for the return type? What is the actual type of a member function?

Comment: You can't overload `.*`. You can overload the `->*` [member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) though, but I would not recommend it. It will make it very hard to read and understand and maintain your code.

Comment: The right-hand side of `->*` must be an expression (typically of type pointer-to-member, but not necessarily if you overload it). A member name alone, like `mem`, is not an expression. You could make something like `(b->*&A::mem)(2)` work with an overload, but that would seem to defeat the purpose; at that point, `b.get().mem(2)` doesn't look that bad.

Comment: Side note: your get should probably return a reference.

Comment: Okay, call me stupid: what's wrong with `A *operator ->() { return &m_a; }`?

Comment: @Quentin I'm sure that's what he is after.  You should make that into an answer.

Comment: @Quentin Just a little confused, with this, `class B's self member function` can not be called with pointer, maybe with `(*B).`.  So why  `writing wrappers for all of the member functions isn't really viable` ?  If you need a wrapper, just write a wrapper.  If you use overload in class B just to call A's function, why just use class A directly?